# I have this eloquent file, but I receive undefined variable

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I want to get a table from my database, I have these files from eloquent laravel, but I don't know why I receive $user undefined variable. I need your help so much because I don't know what to do to finish my project. I need the role_users table, columns user_id and role_id.

**Edit: here is my table named " Events "** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk6We.jpg

The "if" functions should works like that...

```
@if(...role_id == 1)
<i class="icon-user"></i>
@else
<i class="icon-trophy"></i>
```

**Role.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    // protected $fillable = [
    //     'name', 'display_name', 'description',
    // ];
   protected $table = "roles";

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','role_users','role_id','user_id');
    }
}
```

**my view**

```
                            <ul class="list-inline">

                                    <li style="font-style: normal !important"> 
@if( in_array("Organizations", $event->user->roles->pluck('role') )
    <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
@else
    <i class="icon-user"></i> 
@endif


                <a style="margin-left: 2px" href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $event->user->username }}">{{ $event->user->username }}</a></li>
                                    <li style="font-style: normal !important"><i style="margin-right: 3px" class="icon-hotel-restaurant-183 u-line-icon-pro fa-"></i> <a href="{{ url('view-all-event') }}">Event</li>

                                    <li style="font-style: normal !important"><i style="margin-right: 3px" class="icon-notebook fa-"></i> <a href="{{ url('topic') }}/{{ $event->category->category_url  }}">{{ $event->category->category }}</a></li>
                                                                    </ul>
@endforeach

In this case I receive this error:Undefined variable: user (View: /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/resources/views/event/view_all_event.blade.php)
```

**Event.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'subject','information','event_type_id','country','public','category_id','date','added','views','address','city','starts','ends','organizer','telephone','website','email','image_path'
    ];


    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category','category_id','id');
    }

     public function user()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
    }

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','role_users','user_id','role_id');
    }


    public function event_like()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EventLike');
    }

    public function event_comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EventComment');
    }

    public function event_type()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\EventType','event_type_id','id');
    }

    public function country()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country','country','id');
    }

    public function user_participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','events_participants','event_id','user_id');
    }

    public function participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ParticipantType','events_participants','event_id','participant_type');
    }

}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // protected $fillable = [
    //     'name', 'email', 'password',
    // ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // protected $hidden = [
    //     'password', 'remember_token',
    // ];

    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function country()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country','country_id','id');
    }


    public function organization_type()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OrganizationType');
    }

    public function industry()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Industry');
    }


    public function career_path()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CareerPath');
    }


    public function education()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Education');
    }

    public function about()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\About');
    }

    public function portfolio()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Portfolio');
    }

    public function language_skills_selected()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\LanguageSkill','language_skills_selected','user_id','language_skills');
    }

     public function offices_branch()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OfficesBranch');
    }

    public function my_alert()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\MyAlert');
    }

    public function privancy_setting()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PrivancySetting');
    }

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }

    public function news()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\News');
    }

    public function opinion()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Opinion');
    }

    public function career_solution()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CareerSolution');
    }


    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','user_id','contact_id');
    }

    public function invitation()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','invitations','inviter_id','target_id')->withPivot('accepted');
    }

    public function target()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','invitations','target_id','inviter_id','accepted')->withPivot('accepted');
    }

    public function mailbox()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','mailbox','sender_id','target_id')->withPivot('read','subject','message','date','id');
    }

    public function inbox()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','mailbox','target_id','sender_id')->withPivot('read','subject','message','date','id');
    }

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','role_users','user_id','role_id');
    }

    public function evnet_like()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EventLike');
    }

    public function evnet_comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EventComment');
    }

    public function news_like()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\NewsLike');
    }

    public function news_comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\NewsComment');
    }

    public function opinion_like()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OpinionLike');
    }

    public function opinion_comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OpinionComment');
    }

    public function event_participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event','events_participants','user_id','event_id');
    }

    public function participant()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ParticipantType','events_participants','user_id','participant_type');
    }

    public function feed()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Feed');
    }

    public function rss_article()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\RssArticle');
    }

    public static function customPaginate($currentPage,$items,$perPage)
    {
        //Get current page form url e.g. &page=6
        // $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();


        //Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
        $collection = new Collection($items);

        //Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
        $perPage = $perPage;

        //Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
        $currentPageSearchResults = $collection->slice(($currentPage * $perPage)- $perPage, $perPage)->all();

        //Create our paginator and pass it to the view
        $paginatedSearchResults = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageSearchResults, count($collection), $perPage);

       return $paginatedSearchResults;
    }
}
```

I guess that Event.php is for my page ( view-all-event ).

Comment: `$user` is not defined. Perhaps you wanted to do `$event->user`?

Comment: Do you mean by `users` related to `event`?

Comment: I wrote @if($user->event == "Organizations"), but now I have icon-user for all users, do you have a solution for that...?

Comment: Try with `$event->user->role->name`. like `($event->user->role->name == "Organizations")`

Comment: what is column name in table for role is it `role` or `name` ?

Comment: Also share User Model ?

Comment: with $event->user->role doesn't work. I have table "Roles", with columns id(1 individuals, 100 organizations), slug and name, and I have one more, "Role_users", with columns id, user_id, role_id and

Comment: i just posted User.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<li style="font-style: normal !important"> 
@if( in_array("Organizations", $event->user->roles->pluck('role') )
    <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
@else
    <i class="icon-user"></i> 
@endif
</li>
```

To check it user have `Organizations` role or not, if you have created `roles` relation to relate user and roles.

Comment: I have an error syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('

Comment: where it is ? post that line ?

Comment: ```  
         <li style="font-style: normal !important">
         @if( in_array("Organizations", $event->user->roles->pluck('role') ) 
          <i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>
       this line-> 186  @else
          <i class="icon-user"></i>
         @endif  ```

Comment: replace `role` with `name` as you have column name `name` not `role`

Comment: Still have this error... the line is that  <i class="icon-user"></i>. Maybe is somewhere an unfinished line?

Comment: Thank you.I posted all my view now, maybe can be helpful? I have same error :(

Comment: there is no `$user` may be you have in another blade file which is imported here. check in other files ? to check these code just remove all other code.

Comment: Maybe if I post my eventcontroller can help a little? Here is my table from this  page https://imgur.com/a/gcAzv4F . Table name is Events ( for $events ), but here I dont have role_id, only in role_users table.